# Changing Y position of player (code runs like the player has two position simultaneously)

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a game that runs up infinite stairs.

First, I coded prototype code that can run infinite hallway by manipulating the player's Z position and it works.

Then, I change that code to manipulate the player's Y position.
This is `HallWayController` script

```
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        this.handleInfiniteHallway();
    }

    private void handleInfiniteHallway()
    {
        if (this.isPlayerOutOfBounds())
        {
            float posYmod = HALLWAY_HEIGHT;
            if (this.player.position.y > MAX_Y_BOUND)
            {
                posYmod *= -1;
            }
            this.player.position = new Vector3(this.player.position.x, this.player.position.y + posYmod, this.player.position.z);
            Debug.Log("Player Y position: " + this.player.position.y);
        }

    }

    private bool isPlayerOutOfBounds()
    {
        return this.player.position.y > MAX_Y_BOUND || this.player.position.y < MIN_Y_BOUND;
    }
```

With this code, the game malfunctions just like the player have two Y position simultaneously.

What I found:

1. If I use `FixedUpdate()`, the player's position doesn't change on game play view, but `debug.Log` says player Y Position has changed. And if player ever reached `Y_Bound`, code inside `if(this.isPlayterOutOfBounds())`  infinitely executes.
2. If I use `Update()` instead of `FixedUpdate()`, the player's position does change in game play view and `debug.Log`, but sometimes the player flashes back and forth between the original position and repositioned position. And if player ever reached `Y_Bound` code inside `if(this.isPlayterOutOfBounds())`  infinitely executes.

This is `Player Controller` script that linked to the player game object

```
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(CharacterController))]
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float playerSpeed = 10.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpHeight = 1.0f;
    [SerializeField] private float gravityValue = -9.81f;

    private bool isFlashLightOn = true;
    public GameObject lightSource;

    private CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 playerVelocity;
    private bool groundedPlayer;
    private InputManager inputManager;
    private Transform cameraTransform;


    private void Start()
    {
        controller = gameObject.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        inputManager = InputManager.Instance;
        cameraTransform = Camera.main.transform;

        lightSource.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        isFlashLightOn = true;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;
        if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0)
        {
            playerVelocity.y = 0f;
        }

        Vector2 movement = inputManager.GetPlayerMovement();
        Vector3 move = new Vector3(movement.x, 0, movement.y);
        move = cameraTransform.forward * move.z + cameraTransform.right * move.x;
        move.y = 0f;
        controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

        // Changes the height position of the player..
        if (inputManager.PlayerJumped() && groundedPlayer)
        {
            playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);
        }

        playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (inputManager.PlayerFlashLightOn())
        {
            isFlashLightOn = !isFlashLightOn;
            lightSource.gameObject.SetActive(isFlashLightOn);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your `this.player` referring to? `GameObject`or `transform`attached to the GameObject?

Comment: I believe it is transform attached to the GameObject. `public Transform player;`

Comment: Yes it probably is. GameObject doesn't have property position, so it would thrown an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I think I quess what is the problem here. See comments I added

```
// You may call this twice on each frame, depending on your frame rate
void FixedUpdate()
    {
        this.handleInfiniteHallway();
    }

    private void handleInfiniteHallway()
    {
        if (this.isPlayerOutOfBounds())
        {
            // Problem is probably here. When your object hits another limit, you move it all HALLWAY_HEIGHT, so it hits another limit  
            // If you move just half of the height, your character returns to the middle.
            // Original float posYmod = HALLWAY_HEIGHT;
            float posYmod = HALLWAY_HEIGHT / 2;
            if (this.player.position.y > MAX_Y_BOUND)
            {
                posYmod *= -1;
            }
            this.player.position = new Vector3(this.player.position.x, this.player.position.y + posYmod, this.player.position.z);
            Debug.Log("Player Y position: " + this.player.position.y);
        }

    }

    private bool isPlayerOutOfBounds()
    {
        return this.player.position.y > MAX_Y_BOUND || this.player.position.y < MIN_Y_BOUND;
    }
```

If you call FixedUpdate method, it is run twice a frame so position is moved back and forth during one frame. Update method would be called each frame player is jumping between borders.

Comment: I tried your code but it has the same problem. It keeps flashing back and forth between the original position and the new position. I found that even if my position seems to change to a new position, it is affected collision mesh of the original position. So It looks like the character walks through invisible stairs in the sky.

Comment: you log your player y-position. Does that change in log?

Comment: And none of your code does anything with collisions.

Comment: I think it is not a bound value problem. `MAX_Y_BOUND = 58f`, `MIN_Y_BOUND = 0f`, `HALLWAY_HEIGHT = 49f`. Player flashes between Y value `58.5024` and `9.5024`.

Comment: Log says my position has changed to 9.5024.

Comment: And you don't have any other codes linked to your player prefab which could cause that?

Comment: `Character Controller` and `Player Controller` script. I got that script from this youtube video https://youtu.be/5n_hmqHdijM. I'll add that code to my post.

Comment: Just for test. If you remove your Character Control and Player Control from your player and then set your player starting position to y=59 (over the limit) and run your game, does player flash in two position or just move to new position?

Comment: If I remove `Character Control` and `Player Control` and set the player starting position to y=59, it moves to position y=10. it doesn't flashes, just move to the new position.

Comment: Ok, so that means that something your control scripts moves the player back to the original position.

Comment: I Changed `FixedUpdate()` to `Update()` in `PlayerController` script and `Update()` to `FixedUpdate()` in `HallWayController` script and now it all works. Thanks for your help!